# Change (immediatly) submit button text if any form input change [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change **immediately** the submit button text if **any** form input change?

```js
//This applies to whole form
$('#test').change(function() {
  $("#send").prop("value","Change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input id="Input1" value="Input1" />
  <input id="Input2" value="Input2" />
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Here, the button text change **after** the cursor leave the input.

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/rgg3A/56/

Comment: maybe should user `keypress` event instead ? change is only triggered after a blur event.

Comment: @Clementine. what you need ? when enter data in input that time need to change submit value or when click on send that time change value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the listener on the inputs themselves, in this case attach it to the `onKeyDown` event:

```
$('input').on("keydown", function() {
  send.value = "Change";
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/389xwepf/1/)

Answer (score 6):

- Use [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event
- Use [**`:input Selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/), Selects all `input, textarea, select and button` elements

```js
$('#test').find(':input').on('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('send').value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input id="Input1" value="Input1">
  <input id="Input2" value="Input2">
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution requiring minimal change would be to use the `keyup` event. I.e.

```
$('#test').keyup(function() {
   send.value = "Change";
});
```

This way, typing in any of the input fields within the `#test` parent will trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using jquery input [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

```js
$('input').on("keydown", function() {
      $('#send').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
    <input id="Input1" value="Input1">
    <input id="Input2" value="Input2">
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your original question did not mention JQuery directly except by it's use as a selector, this one left me hanging for a proper JavaScript answer.

So this answer is the same as the other examples, but using just plain ol' JavaScript. Uses the [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, just as the other answers do.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('send').value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input id="Input1" value="Input1">
  <input id="Input2" value="Input2">
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

The difference here is that it is listening for bubbled events on the form element proper, registers an event listener only once (instead of applying the same event listener to multiple elements), and using the [**`Event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property to figure out which element was modified.